# Error running matlab code after compiling

Tags: matlab, matrix, compiler-construction, executable

It looks like this has been asked many times, but none of the past posts seem to solve my question. All those had to do with matrix/vector while my code does not have any of these, just simple variables. It takes three variables as arguments. It works perfectly fine within the Matlab environment. I only got the error when I compiled it with mcc -m Normal.m and tried to run with the executable like this "./Normal 1 5 0.5". The complete error message is:

```
Error using /
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Normal (line 4)



MATLAB:dimagree
```

It is complaining about line 4: N=2/dt, what is wrong with this?

Here is the code:

```
function val=Normal(l1,l2,dt)

const=(l2/l1-1);
N=2/dt;

S=1.0/sqrt(l2/l1);
Z(1)=S;

for i=2:N
    t= -1+(i-1)*dt;
    Z(i)=1.0/sqrt(const*t*t+1);
    S=S+2*Z(i);
end
Z(21)=1.0/(l2/l1);
S=S+1.0/sqrt(l2/l1);

val=dt*S/2;


end
```

Comment: Did my answer make sense? It's unexpected to receive numerical arguments as strings, but that's what happens when passing via the command line this way.

Comment: @chappjc yes it makes perfect sense. I will give it a try. THanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But `dt` is not a scalar when passed into the standalone through the command `./Normal 1 5 0.5`.  It is a character array with 3 elements (`'0'`, `'.'`,`'5'`)!

When passing numerical arguments to a standalone, [they are passed *as strings*](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92537).  Thus, inside the function, you need to convert `'0.5'` into a double, and similarly for `l1` and `l2`:

```
dt = str2num(dt);
l1 = str2num(l1);
l2 = str2num(l2);
```

Note that you can use [`isdeployed`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/isdeployed.html) to determine at runtime if the function is a standalone:

```
if isdeployed, dt = str2num(dt); end
```

And you might need to display the result:

```
if isdeployed, disp(val); end
```

Result:

```
>> system('Normal 1 5 0.5');
    1.4307
>> Normal(1,5,0.5) % .m function for comparison
ans =
    1.4307
```